# Learning promises and exceptions vs. rejecting in Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm under the impression that an exception inside a promise will trigger the subsequent fail-handler, but I'm not seeing it happen in this code:

```
var Q = require('q');

function x() {
  console.log('x');
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log('resolving x');
        deferred.resolve('hi');
      },
      1000
  );

  return deferred.promise;
}

function y() {
  console.log('y');
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log('throwing in y');
        throw new Error('Oih!');
      },
      1000
  );

  return deferred.promise;
}

x().then(y).then(
    function () {
      console.log('yes');
    },
    function () {
      console.log('no');
    }
);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing callbacks and promises + you have a case of deferred anti-pattern. Either use `Q.delay` or a wrapper like:

```
function delay(ms) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(d.resolve, ms);
    return d.promise;
}
```

Now that there is promise API for timeouts, there is no reason to use setTimeout:

```
function x() {
    return delay(1000).then(function () {
        console.log("hi");
    });
}

function y() {
    return delay(1000).then(function () {
        console.log('throwing in y');
        throw new Error('Oih!');
    });
}
```

Use:

```
x()
.then(y)
.then(function() {
    console.log('yes');
})
.catch(function(e) {
     console.log('no');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions inside a promise chain are catched. You must either manage a failing promise as you did, or end the promise chain using `done()` in order to expose and throw the error (see [the documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-end)).

However, the error you're throwing in the `setTimeout` is not related to the promise as the error is thrown asynchronously, see for instance [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504429/using-q-promises-how-to-catch-an-async-throw). The alternative is to reject the promise like this:

```
function y() {
  console.log('y');
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log('throwing in y');
        deferred.reject(new Error('Oih!'));
      },
      1000
  );

  return deferred.promise;
}
```