# Asynchronous exception handling with bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

What is the best way to handle this scenario. I am in a controlled environment and I don't want to crash.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function getPromise(){
    return new Promise(function(done, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
                throw new Error("AJAJAJA");
        }, 500);
    });
}

var p = getPromise();
    p.then(function(){
        console.log("Yay");
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log("Rejected",e);
    }).catch(Error, function(e){
        console.log("Error",e);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log("Unknown", e);
    });
```

When throwing from within the setTimeout we will always get:

```
$ node bluebird.js

c:\blp\rplus\bbcode\scratchboard\bluebird.js:6
                throw new Error("AJAJAJA");
                      ^
Error: AJAJAJA
    at null._onTimeout (c:\blp\rplus\bbcode\scratchboard\bluebird.js:6:23)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

If the throw occurs before the setTimeout then bluebirds catch will pick it up:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function getPromise(){

    return new Promise(function(done, reject){
        throw new Error("Oh no!");
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("hihihihi")
        }, 500);
    });
}

var p = getPromise();
    p.then(function(){
        console.log("Yay");
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log("Rejected",e);
    }).catch(Error, function(e){
        console.log("Error",e);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log("Unknown", e);
    });
```

Results in:

```
$ node bluebird.js
Error [Error: Oh no!]
```

Which is great - but how would one handle a rogue async callback of this nature in node or the browser.

Comment: Wrap the settimeout (or asynchronous method) in a promise so it gets handled just like everything else.

Comment: See also [Using Q.promises: how to catch an async throw?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15504429/1048572)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Promises are not [domains](http://www.nodejs.org/api/domain.html), they will not catch exceptions from asynchronous callbacks. You just can't do that.

Promises do however catch exceptions that are thrown from within a `then` / `catch` / `Promise` constructor callback. So use

```
function getPromise(){
    return new Promise(function(done, reject){
        setTimeout(done, 500);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("hihihihi");
        throw new Error("Oh no!");
    });
}
```

(or just [`Promise.delay`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisedelaydynamic-value-int-ms---promise)) to get the desired behaviour. Never throw in custom (non-promise) async callbacks, always reject the surrounding promise. Use `try-catch` if it really needs to be.

Comment: What if I don't have control over what is happening in the method invoked by setTimeout? Wrap in another promise per @Kevin B's suggestion?

Comment: No. When it's out of control, then you can't catch the error. File a bug against that library that you need to gain control.

Comment: Hmm, checking what mocha is doing under the hood, as seems to handle something like:     it("should respond with hello world", function(done) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            throw new Error("ouch");
            done();
        }, 500);
    }); very gracefully. But probably not with promises.

Comment: In the browser, it might use `window.onerror`, in node it might use domains.

Comment: In the runner: process.on('uncaughtException', uncaught);

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with the same scenario and needs you are describing, i've discovered [zone.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js) , an amazing javascript library , used in multiple frameworks (Angular is one of them), that allows us to handle those scenarios in a very elegant way.

> A Zone is an execution context that persists across async tasks. You can think of it as thread-local storage for JavaScript VMs

Using your example code :

```js
import 'zone.js'

function getPromise(){
  return new Promise(function(done, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      throw new Error("AJAJAJA");
    }, 500);
  });
}

Zone.current
  .fork({
    name: 'your-zone-name',
    onHandleError: function(parent, current, target, error) {
      // handle the error 
      console.log(error.message) // --> 'AJAJAJA'
      // and return false to prevent it to be re-thrown
      return false
    }
  })
  .runGuarded(async () => {
    await getPromise()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Bergi. Now i know promise does not catch error in async callback. Here is my 3 examples i have tested.

Note: After call reject, function will continue running.

Example 1: reject, then throw error in promise constructor callback

Example 2: reject, then throw error in setTimeout async callback

Example 3: reject, then return in setTimeout async callback to avoid crashing

```
// Caught
// only error 1 is sent
// error 2 is reached but not send reject again
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("error 1"); // Send reject
  console.log("Continue"); // Print 
  throw new Error("error 2"); // Nothing happen
})
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error", err);
  });


// Uncaught
// error due to throw new Error() in setTimeout async callback
// solution: return after reject
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject("error 1"); // Send reject
    console.log("Continue"); // Print

    throw new Error("error 2"); // Did run and cause Uncaught error
  }, 0);
})
  .then(data => {})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error", err);
  });


// Caught
// Only error 1 is sent
// error 2 cannot be reached but can cause potential uncaught error if err = null
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const err = "error 1";
    if (err) {
      reject(err); // Send reject
      console.log("Continue"); // Did print
      return;
    }
    throw new Error("error 2"); // Potential Uncaught error if err = null
  }, 0);
})
  .then(data => {})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error", err);
  });
```