# Promise constructor with reject call vs throwing error

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    throw 'test1';
});

var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('test2');
});

p1.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err); // test1
});

p2.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err); // test2
});
```

Is there any difference between using `reject` (in `p2`) from the `Promise` api, and throwing an error (in `p1`) using `throw`?

Its exactly the same?

If its the same, why we need a `reject` callback then?

Comment: Think about `new Promise(_, reject) { setTimeout(reject, 1000); })`. You can't do that with `throw`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Is there any difference between using `reject` (in `p2`) from the `Promise` api, and throwing an error (in `p1`) using `throw`?

Yes, you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25143476/1048572) use `throw` asynchronously, while `reject` is a callback. For example, some timeout:

```
new Promise(_, reject) {
    setTimeout(reject, 1000);
});
```

> Its exactly the same?

No, at least not when other code follows your statement. `throw` immediately completes the resolver function, while calling `reject` continues execution normally - after having "marked" the promise as rejected.

Also, engines might provide different exception debugging information if you `throw` error objects.

For your specific example, you are right that `p1` and `p2` are indistinguishable from the outside.

Comment: 'Engines might provide different exception debugging information if you throw error objects.' - I don't think this part is true for throw vs reject or do you mean that in general?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hm, I thought I had encountered an engine that distinguished in its stack traces between creating and throwing errors. Can't remember which :-/

Comment: If you find one be sure to file a bug report - Errors create stack traces when created and not when thrown :)

Comment: In frameworks like Angular2 using throw would also trigger the Angular ErrorHandler while using reject avoids that.

Answer (score 36):

I know this is a bit late, but I don't really think either of these answers completely answers the questions I had when I found this, Here is a fuller example to play with.

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    throw 'test 1.1'; //This actually happens
    console.log('test 1.1.1'); //This never happens
    reject('test 1.2'); //This never happens because throwing an error already rejected the promise
    console.log('test 1.3'); //This never happens
});

var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('test 2.1'); //This actually happens
    console.log('test 2.1.1'); //This happens BEFORE the Promise is rejected because reject() is a callback
    throw 'test 2.2'; //This error is caught and ignored by the Promise
    console.log('test 2.3'); //This never happens
});

var p3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { reject('test 3.1');}, 1000); //This never happens because throwing an error already rejected the promise
    throw('test 3.2'); //This actually happens
    console.log('test 3.3'); //This never happens
});

var p4 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    throw('test 4.1'); //This actually happens
    setTimeout(function() { reject('test 4.2');}, 1000); //This never happens because throwing an error already rejected the promise
    console.log('test 4.3'); //This never happens
});

var p5 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { throw('test 5.1');}, 1000); //This throws an Uncaught Error Exception
    reject('test 5.2'); //This actually happens
    console.log('test 5.3'); //This happens BEFORE the Promise is rejected because reject() is a callback
});

var p6 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('test 6.1'); //This actually happens
    setTimeout(function() { throw('test 6.2');}, 1000); //This throws an Uncaught Error Exception
    console.log('test 6.3'); //This happens BEFORE the Promise is rejected because reject() is a callback
});


p1.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test1
});

p2.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test2
});

p3.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test3
});

p4.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test4
});

p5.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test5
});

p6.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve, "resolved")
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject, "rejected")
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, "caught"); // test6
});
```

Answer (score 32):

No, there is not, the two are completely identical. The only difference and why we need `reject` is when you need to reject asynchronously - for example if you're converting a callback based API it might need to signal an asynchronous error.

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    someCallbackApi(function(err, data){
        if(err) reject(err); // CAN'T THROW HERE, non promise context, async.
        else resolve(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: probably because you say 'completely identical' and then go on to explain the difference...?

Comment: @PeterWhitfield that's still OK from what I can tell - they are _completely identical within OP's use case_, however given _other input in another usage pattern_ they differ.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting observation is that if you use `throw` it will be handled by first the `reject` handler & then the`error` handler if a reject handler is not in place.

**With reject handler block**

```js
var allowed = false;
var p1 = new Promise(
function(resolve, reject) {
  if (allowed)
    resolve('Success');
  else
//         reject('Not allowed');
    throw new Error('I threw an error')
})

p1.then(function(fulfilled) {
console.log('Inside resolve handler, resolved value: ' + fulfilled);
}, function(rejected) {
console.log('Inside reject handler, rejected value: ' + rejected);
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log('Inside error handler, error value: ' + error);
})
```

**Without reject handler block**

```js
var allowed = false;
var p1 = new Promise(
function(resolve, reject) {
  if (allowed)
    resolve('Success');
  else
//         reject('Not allowed');
    throw new Error('I threw an error')
})

p1.then(function(fulfilled) {
console.log('Inside resolve handler, resolved value: ' + fulfilled);
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log('Inside error handler, error value: ' + error);
})
```

Additionally, the catch block will be able catch any error thrown inside the `resolve` handler.

```js
var allowed = true;
var p1 = new Promise(
function(resolve, reject) {
  if (allowed)
    resolve('Success');
  else
//         reject('Not allowed');
    throw new Error('I threw an error')
})

p1.then(function(fulfilled) {
console.log('Inside resolve handler, resolved value: ' + fulfilled);
throw new Error('Error created inside resolve handler block');
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log('Inside error handler, error value: ' + error);
})
```

It looks like it's best to use `throw`, unless you can't if you are running some async task, you will have to pass the `reject` callback down to the async function. But there's a work around, that is is to promisifying your async function. More on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446005