# Promisifying an API

Tags: javascript, promise, q

If I want to promisify all code paths in `myFunction`, do I need to create a `deferred` inside `myFunction`?

```
function myFunction(options) {
  if(!options) {
    throw 'foo'; // But I want the API for myFunction to be promise-based...
  } 

  return promiseBasedApi.doSomethingAndReturnPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I need to create a deferred inside `myFunction`?

(That's jQuery terminology, the general case would be "Do I need to create a promise in my function?")

**Only** if your function doesn't already have a promise it can return; frequently, it does, if it's waiting on any asynchronous operation (ajax, some other promise-based API, etc.) to complete.

---

> ```
>   if(!options) {
>       throw 'foo'; // But I want the API for myFunction to be promise-based...
>   }
> ```

If you're asking if you need to create an reject a promise for the error that `options` is not provided, no, I wouldn't expect that of an API. There are two aspects to an asynchronous operation's API:

1. Initiation
2. Completion

In the above, failing to supply `options` is an error during the *initiation* of the request. I would expect an inline exception, not an asynchronous error callback.

Errors *processing* the request (HTTP failures, etc.) would be errors I'd expect via the promise's rejection mechanism.

Comment: Actually I am using the q library, so I picked it up from there.. So if I want to completely "promisify" this function then I need to return a rejected promise in the exceptional case (`throw foo;`)? Do you know if there is a shorthand to do this in q? (Point taken re initiation and completion), but this question still stands.)

Comment: @BenAston: Best to mention or tag if you're using a specific library. My view is that you don't need to return a rejected promise for the above; I would throw an exception as you're doing (see the second half of my answer, which I may have added while you were writing your comment). I'm afraid I can't help with the specifics of the Q library, but most promise libs have a means of creating a rejected promise.

Comment: The initiation vs completion concept. Is that your own idea or from a book (if so, which one)?

Comment: @BenAston: I don't think I made it up, but it's not from a book either. It's just the nature of asynchronous processing: Initiation, Processing, Completion. Only the first and last really have an API presence. :-)

Comment: "That's jQuery terminology" - To be fair, not only jQuery. Some other libs offer deferreds. Q is one such lib.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Yeah -- see Ben's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a deferred or the `Promise` constructor in your function. You do need those *only* for non-promise-based APIs. Even then, you should [not use it globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32160991/1048572), but a separate promise capability for each asynchronous code path.

In your case, you should just return a rejected promise instead of throwing:

```
function myFunction(options) {
  if (!options) {
    return Promise.reject(new FooError()); // as promised!
  } 

  return promiseBasedApi.doSomethingAndReturnPromise();
}
```

An alternative, if you are using Bluebird, would be to wrap your throwing-or-(promise)-returning function in [`Promise.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html). See also [Should an async API ever throw synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572) and [Should a Promise.reject message be wrapped in Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572) for related discussions.