# Bluebird<void> is not assignable to Bluebird<ProcessInstance> in return statment

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, bluebird

I'm trying to return a promise with an `.try(function(){}).catch(function(){})` block.
 My problem is caused by the type of my promise.

```
    deleteProcess(processId: number): Promise<ProcessInstance> {
    let deletedProcess = this.Process.findById(processId);

    return Promise
        .try(function () {
            this.Process.destroy({
                where: {
                    processId: processId
                }
            })
                .then(function (rowDeleted) {
                    if (rowDeleted === 1) {
                        console.log('Deleted successfully');
                        return this.getDeletedProcess();
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        });

    function getDeletedProcess(): ProcessInstance {
        return this.deletedProcess;
    };
};
```

The error says, that type 'Bluebird void' is not assignable to type 'Bluebird ProcessInstance'

Comment: Please make this code sample syntactically valid first.

Comment: I changed the code

Answer (score 0):

This post was really helpful to solve the problem

[Bluebird.JS Promise: new Promise(function (resolve, reject){}) vs Promise.try(function(){})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148305/bluebird-js-promise-new-promisefunction-resolve-reject-vs-promise-tryfu)

This solves the problem:

```
    return new Promise<ProcessInstance>(
        (function (resolve, reject) {
            this.Process.destroy({
                where: {
                    processId: processId
                }
            })
                .then(function (rowDeleted) {
                    if (rowDeleted === 1) {
                        console.log('Deleted successfully');
                        return this.getDeletedProcess();
                    }
                })
                reject(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        })
        )
```