# $http propagate errors in promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

so in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EToqyWNd54JSYLSVkipV?p=preview) I demonstrate a failing `$http` request.

The responsibility of the service is to deconstruct the server response and to ready the information for the controller to consume.

When it errors, I feel like I need to propagate the error to the controller *not for handling* but for being able to inform the user that the operation couldn't complete. (handling in a sense of logging etc.)

As it stands:

```
return $http.get('notgoing')
  .then(
    function success(result) {
      return result.data;
    },
    function error(err) {
      console.warn(err); // do something meaningful with the error

      return err;
    }
  );
```

this will rollup the error or success into the chained promise's success function. This isn't ideal for informing the user.

Is there a simple way to get the error function to bubble the value as an error to the next chained promise's error function. (bearing in mind I don't really want to take a dependency on the `$q` library and have another promise interwoven with the `$http` promise)

**- OR -**

Does the responsibility of handling that error stop at the service.

Comment: Just a little addon: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703407/2375913) explains the difference between using `throw` and `reject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `return err;`, throw it with `throw err;`. `$q` will handle the "uncaught" error and reject the chain.

Comment: Genius.... I thought that throw would cause the entire app to bomb out. But fair enough!

Comment: can you provide some explanation or just another link :)

Comment: @Shreyas to be fair if you take that throw and stick it into the plnkr there is enough explanation?

Comment: thanks but I want to know the difference it would make while calling, as per my understanding it will call the error part of .then insted of success?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way without using `$q`, but Angular brings its own implementation along, so all you need to do is to inject it into your service and then call `$q.reject(err)`. Otherwise Angular will think your error has already been handled inside the service.

```
angular.module('test', []).factory('testService', function ($http, $q) {
  ...  
  function test() {
    return $http.get('notgoing').then(function success(result) {
      return result.data;
    }, function error(err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return $q.reject(err);
    });
  }
});
```

Check the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WNwyuGIKzH2J4MAWrvNI?p=preview).

Comment: I did say I wanted to avoid this pattern. I do know of this.

Comment: I know, but I thought there was no other way (which is incorrect). May I ask why you wish to avoid `$q`?