# Are Promise.resolve and new Promise(resolve) interchangeable

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, rsvp.js

I think `Promise.resolve` and `new Promise(resolve)` are interchangeable.

Consider this:

A.

```
new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}).then(function () {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve("HI")
    });
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

B.

```
new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}).then(function () {
    return RSVP.resolve("HI");
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Both print "HI" as I expected.

So I think if I don't need to "reject" anything. I can just write `RSVP.resolve();` for simplicity.

But consider this example:

```
new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}).then(function () {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("HI")
        }, 3000);
    });
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

How can I use `RSVP.resolve();` to replace? I tried for example:

```
new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}).then(function () {
    return setTimeout(function () {
        return new RSVP.resolve("HI");
    }, 3000);
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This prints something else instead of "HI". So is it possible to use RSVP.resolve(); here? Are these two interchangeable?

Comment: You've got the same issue as in [Promise constructor with reject call vs throwing error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28703241/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost

> I think Promise.resolve and new Promise(resolve) are interchangeable.

Nope. `Promise.resolve` will create a promise which is already resolved, whereas `new Promise(resolve)` creates a promise which is neither resolved nor rejected.

---

In the last example,

```
return setTimeout(function () {
    return new RSVP.resolve("HI");
}, 3000);
```

means that, you are returning the result of `setTimeout` function, not a promise object. So, the current `then` handler will return a resolved promise with the result of `setTimeout`. That is why you are seeing a weird object.

---

In your particular case, you want to introduce a delay before resolving the promise. It is not possible with `Promise.resolve`. The penultimate method you have shown in the question, is the way to go.

Comment: could you tell me when to use RSVP.resolve() is preferred?

Comment: @CSnerd Whenever you need to create a promise which is already resolved. For example, let's say you are writing a function which queries the internet for the given word. Since the querying is an asynchronous task, you return a Promise from it. But you don't want to do the querying everytime, as it is very slow. So, you cache the result of the query in a JavaScript object. Next time when the request comes for the same keyword, you need to return a promise but with the values, not doing an async operation. In that case, you can simply do `if (k in cache) return Promise.resolve(cache[k])`