# Best practice: Promises reject/throw

Tags: promise, ecmascript-6, angular-promise, bluebird, es6-promise

**Background**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703241/promise-constructor-with-reject-call-vs-throwing-error) suggests that using `throw` inside a promise function is effectively identical to calling the `reject` callback.

e.g. These are equivalent:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error("sadface"); // Using throw
}).catch(function(e) {
  // ... handle error
});
```

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject(new Error("sadface")); // Using reject
}).catch(function(e) {
  // ... handle error
});
```

---

**Question**

Obviously, if there's async code involved (such as an database or HTTP request), you can't use `throw`, since the stack has changed.

As a "best practice", should I then *always* use `reject` inside a promise to keep things consistent? Or should `throw` still be used under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously, if there's async code involved (such as an database or HTTP request), you can't use throw, since the stack has changed.

That's half the point of promises. **Promises are throw safe**, they let you use sync facilities like `return` and `throw` in asynchronous code.

Synchronous:

```
try {
   return fn(); 
} catch (e) {
   // handle error
   return recover(e);
}
```

Promises:

```
fn().catch(recover);
```

Or more verbosely:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return fn();
}).catch(function(e) { 
    return recover(e);
});
```

Comment: So, you're saying I can throw inside a setTimeout inside of a promise?

Comment: @aaaidan no, you can [convert it to a promise returning function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) and then throw inside that - promise code is effectively wrapped in a `try/catch` that converts `throw`s to rejections.

Comment: Right, so I guess my question is more broadly about whether you should use `resolve/reject` as a matter of course (instead of `return/throw`), or whether it's sometimes good practice to `return/throw`, to clarify intent, say. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @aaaidan prefer `throw` to `return` if it is possible, when you `return` a rejected promise it's effectively like doing `function fn(err){ throw err}; return fn(Error);` which is not as nice as `throw err` :D

Comment: This is where "best practice" gets tough, since I'd have suggested the opposite :) Returning a rejection wouldn't cause an abrupt completion in JS, so I'd expect it to be faster, and then you don't mix error-handling paradigms.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You mean "prefer throw to _reject_" ?

Comment: @loganfsmyth That's the sort of info I'm interested in an answer... ;)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In `new Promise`, I'd prefer `reject(new Error())` over `throw new Error()`. In `.then` I'd prefer `return Promise.reject(new Error())` over `throw new Error()`. My point is mostly that this seems kind of subjective. Do whatever you like best :)