# When should I use Q.defer and when just Promise.resolve/reject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, deferred

I'm using nodejs and was wondering when should I use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) defer, and when just use Promise.resolve/reject?

I saw a lot of examples of both kinds, for example:

```
// with Q defer
fucntion oneWay(myVal) {
  var deffered = Q.defer();
  if (myVal < 0) {
    deffered.reject(new Error('nope'));
  } else {
    deffered.resolve('yay');
  }
  return deffered.promise;
}

// native Promise
fucntion orAnother(myVal) {
  if (myVal < 0) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('nope'));
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('yay');
  }
}
```

What's the difference, and when is a good practice to use difer?

Is there any difference between Promise.resolve/reject (native) and Q.resolve/reject? They both return promise but it looks different when I look at the return value in node console.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear the context (frontend FW as Angular, node app etc) and what are you referencing with Promise (native ES6 promises, a libray like Bluebird?)

Comment: you're right. I've made it clearer (node and native promise)

Comment: They're more or less alternative implementation of the same idea. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: If you have access to native promises I suggest you to use it and do not import an external lib to just do something you can accomplish without it.
If you need some more promise features take a look at [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) or [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when) libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor, or - [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692824/1048572) - a deferred, when you don't need to. There's nothing asynchronous in your functions, so you don't need (and should not use) callbacks.

Just go for `Promise.resolve`/`Promise.reject` or their `Q` counterparts and construct a promise of a value directly. It's much shorter and simpler anyway.

See also [Promise constructor with reject call vs throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28703241/1048572).

> When is a good practice to use defer?

Never. Even in `Q`, you should use [`Q.Promise`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#user-content-qpromiseresolver).

> Is there any difference between Promise (native) and Q? They look different when I look at the return value in node console.

Well, they're different classes, with different properties, and `Q` promises do have more methods.
They do work the same though, and are completely interoperable with each other.

Comment: so there's never a need for defer? (also in async functions?)

Comment: Yes, `defer` is deprecated by the promise constructor entirely.

Comment: great, thanks! it was really confusing cause even in [Q's documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds) they show the use of defer