# Return new promise Q in ternary condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q

Im using the following code which is working OK.

Now I need to return promise resolve but not sure how to do it in this case, there is nice way to do it?
please ignore that the code **is sync** we are working on a tool which every external API method s**hould return promise**

This is the code

```
getExtendedFileContent: function(sHTML, aConfig) {
    var oDeferred = Q.defer();
    return aConfig ? this._process(sHTML, aConfig) : sHTML;
},
```

the `this._process(sHTML, aConfig)`  & the `sHTML` should return

> oDeferred.promise;

Comment: What is `sHTML` a string? and what `this._process(sHTML, aConfig)` returns?

Comment: `q.resolve(value)` to return a resolved promise.

Comment: Your `getExtendedFileContent` should only return the promise (`oDeferred.promise`). You should then resolve this promise with the values returned by either `sHTML` or `this._process(sHTML, aConfig)`

Comment: @Satpal - sHTML is string and the process function return string either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Q.defer`. Just use the [`Q` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue) (or `Promise.resolve` if you're working with an ES6-compatible promise libary):

```
function getExtendedFileContent(sHTML, aConfig) {
    return Q(aConfig ? this._process(sHTML, aConfig) : sHTML);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it will be great to explain why you against the q.defer since I saw many places where people use it...

Comment: @NinaS: To avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), mostly :-) It's just not necessary, adds complexity and introduces likelihood of errors. Also you should be using [`Q.Promise` instead of `Q.defer` anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28692824/1048572) (when you really need it, which is rare enough given Q's great promisification helpers). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35312418/1048572)