# Catching an error thrown inside setinterval function in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

```
this.custFunc = Bluebird.method(function (id)) {

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
                calc(id)
                .then(function (flag) {
                    if (flag) {
                        execProg(id, interval);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return Bluebird.reject(err);
                });
            }, pollingInterval);
});
```

How do I catch the error being thrown inside the setinterval function? I am not able to figure it out?

Comment: What about using [`Promise.delay()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisedelaydynamic-value-int-ms---promise) with recursive function

Comment: @aarosil Instead of using setInterval?

Comment: What exactly throws an exception, `calc` or `execProg`?

Comment: What do you think would `custFunc` return, as the interval is infinite?

Comment: @Bergi Both function can throw errors! My execProg will clear the interval, so it is not infinite

Comment: Right.  Don't use `setInterval` just use `.delay()` and call the fn again from within itself.

Comment: Note that recursive setTimeout and setInterval both behave differently, which do you actually need?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I catch the error being thrown inside the setinterval function?

You cannot. It's an asynchronous callback, and promises don't catch those. You could be explicitly doing `try catch` (or `Promise.try`), but that's not the right solution. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25143476/1048572).

> I am not able to figure it out

`setInterval` doesn't work well together with promises, which represent a single result. Your `custFunc` doesn't return a promise for the end of the interval, which it is supposed to be.

You can make everything much simpler by refactoring this to a recursive solution:

```
this.custFunc = function(id) {
    return Promise.delay(pollingInterval).then(function() {
        return calc(id);
    }).then(function(flag) {
        if (flag) {
            return execProg(id);
        }
    }).bind(this).then(function() {
        if (/*you want to break the interval*/)
            return result;
        else
            return this.custFunc(id);
    });
});
```

You might need to restructure `execProg` a bit to signal *continue*/*break* as a return value instead of by calling `clearInterval` - or alternatively just make the recursive call from within `execProg`.

If you depend on the steady timing of `setInterval` (without being influenced by the execution time of the async(!) `calc` and `execProg` functions), you might want to call `Promise.delay` immediately and [cancel](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) it later if no longer needed. Alternatively, implement an [accurate timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972322/1048572).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: thanks, embarrassing mistake :-/

Comment: Any time, just waiting for OP to confirm this is an OK alternative to `setInterval` before voting :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Why wouldn't it? OK, `execProg` will need to be restructured a bit to signal *continue* / *break* as a return value vs. calling `clearInterval`, but I don't see any other proper solution.

Comment: Well, for one thing `setTimeout` with recursion and `setInterval` [behave differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/729943/1348195) in how they execute. This is possible with `setInterval` but you'd have to use a promise constructor that rejects when any promise rejects and resolves when the interval is cleared (through a second interval checking that, probably).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: To my knowledge, `setInterval` drifts as much as `setinterval`, though it doesn't depend on the timing between the calls. I'll amend my answer though.

Comment: Your answer is fine, OP just needs to clarify :) They both "drift" but setTimeout's drifts aggregate afaik.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Ah, but you've raised an important point, as `calc` and `execProg` are supposedly asynchronous, the recursive `setTimeout`/`delay` drifts really hard.