# Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling - After Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-next

Their is already a question on this topic

[Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

which is old and answers are very much outdated, `domains` have even deprecated since then.

Now in a post Async/Await Node.js scenario shouldn't we consider sync and async cases similarly and throw exceptions in sync functions and rejecting promises in async functions instead of returning an `Error` instance in the former case.

```
let divideSync = function(x,y) {
    // if error condition?
    if ( y === 0 ) {
        // "throw" the error 
        throw new Error("Can't divide by zero exception")
    }
    else {
        // no error occured, continue on
        return x/y
    }
}
```

Simulating async divide operation

```
let divideAsync = function(x, y) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      // if error condition?
      if (y === 0) {
        // "throw" the error safely by rejecting the promise
        reject (new Error("Can't divide by zero exception"));
      } else {
        // no error occured, continue on
        resolve(x / y)
      }
    }, 1000);
  })

};
```

So sync and async exceptions can be handled in a uniform manner

```
let main = async function () {
    try {
        //const resultSync = divideSync(4,0);
        const resultAsync = await divideAsync(4,0);
    }
    catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The answers from [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7310521/1048572) are old and very much outdated

Not that much. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36703397/1048572), with the list from [this well-maintained blog post](http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practices-of-node-js-error-handling/), is quite up to date.
[The offical node.js guide](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors) is always a good read, and the general approach hasn't changed that much.

So what has changed?

- Domains are broken and deprecated. Well, that's old news.
- The typical "node-style callbacks" with their error-first-parameter, which are fired exactly once, should no more be used. This simple sequential asynchronous coding style with all its problems has been superseeded by promises and `async`/`await`. (*Note: event emitters etc are a different case*)
- `process.on('uncaughtException')` is supplemented by [`process.on('unhandledRejection')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28709666/1048572)
- promises also catch programmer errors *if used correctly*. For boring sequential asynchronous code, they can replace domains.

So what does this mean for the common code?

> Shouldn't we consider sync and async cases similarly and throw exceptions in sync functions and rejecting promises in async functions instead of returning an `Error` instance?

Yes, exactly. You should reject your promises with `Error`s (or `throw` them from `async function`s).

Notice you will rarely have to call `reject` yourself. With promises, you should be able to `throw` in your code. If you can't, you're likely not using them correctly - and programmer mistakes wouldn't be caught either there.

The golden rule for this code is: **Never use callbacks** that are not promise callbacks. "Promise callbacks" refers to the `new Promise`, `then`, and `catch` arguments, and possibly some of the custom methods of your library (e.g. `finally`). This is where your example code above has a problem. Written correctly, it should read

```
async function divideAsync(x, y) {
    await new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000) // don't even pass a function expression
    );
    if (y === 0) {
        throw new Error("Can't divide by zero exception");
    } else {
        return x / y;
    }
}
```

Comment: So as a rule if an asynchronous function uses async then throw the error and  if not then reject the error

Comment: No, even if a function doesn't use `async` syntax, but employs promises, you can and should `throw` (or `return Promise.reject(…)` if you prefer) from promise callbacks, like `divideAsync = (x, y) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)).then(() => { if (y === 0) throw new Error(…) else return x / y })`

Comment: Why exception is not caught (unhandled) if I throw the error in my version of code

Comment: Because you're throwing in a `setTimeout` callback, not a promise callback. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25143476/1048572)