# Throwing in nested async function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function like this:

```
async function testFunction() {
    await doSomeWork();

    const sshClient = new SSHClient();
    sshClient.on('error', async error => {
        throw error;
    });
    sshClient.connect();
}
```

And Im using it like this:

```
testFunction().then(() => {
    // when an error happens in sshClient I end up here
}).catch(error => {
    // and not here
});
```

Is there a way to catch an error which is thrown in a nested async function?

Comment: Does your `sshClient` have an event when the connection *succeeds* as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous exception handling with bluebird promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143476/asynchronous-exception-handling-with-bluebird-promises)