# Is there a javascript promise library that handles runtime errors?

Tags: parse-platform, promise, q, bluebird

So far I've tried comparing `Parse.Promise`, `Q` and `Bluebird` but I haven't been able to get an `error` or `catch` block to handle/capture an async runtime error.

If you believe that one of the libraries mentioned above, can handle/capture async runtime errors and suspect that I may not have written my sample code correctly, please feel free to point out any mistakes: https://github.com/pulkitsinghal/example-promises

Otherwise I'm looking for suggestions for other promise libraries or frameworks to explore.

Comment: Please post the code here and what errors you expect to be caught.

Comment: duplicate of [Using Q.promises: how to catch an async throw?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15506719/1048572)

Comment: duplicate of [Asynchronous exception handling with bluebird promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25143476/1048572)

Comment: Those two are very close but are not exact duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply impossible for a *library* to handle errors beyond its control. The only reason promise libraries are throw safe is because promises use return values to assimilate other promises.

If all your code returns promises instead of callbacks, All A+ promise libraries (that's Q and Bluebird in your example but not Parse.promise) will catch runtime errors and bluebird will even report them automatically without the need to `.catch` them.

Domains are being deprecated and don't really work well in practice and there is no node-wide solution. Your only option really is to stick to promises app-wide. You *must* kill and restart the server on an uncaught exception since some parts in node code that throw those do not clean very well after themselves when they throw (this is part of why domains are deprecated to begin with).

So:

- Promises *are* throw safe for runtime errors if you use promises app-wide.
- If you have to run untrusted code that might throw consider running it in a VM using the vm module.
- Sometimes there are node errors that leave you no choice but to restart a server.
- Promisify at *the lowest level possible* to avoid promisified functions throwing.

[Here is a broader question that discusses async error-handling in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301839/javascript-asynchronous-exception-handling-with-node-js).